# How can I make a list that contains specific values from another list?

Tags: python

I am new to python and I need to take a list populated with numerical values and create a sublist containing specific values from that list.

The original list contains 16,419 individual numerical values. I need to make multiple lists from this original that contain 4500 values each.

Sample code (pretend the length of 'Original_List' is 16419):

```
Original_List = [46325, 54326, 32666, 32453, 54325, 32542, 38573]

First_4500_Numbers = []
First_4500_Numbers.append(List_of_16419_Indivudual_Numbers[0:4499])
```

The above code is creating a list that looks like this:

```
print(First_4500_Numbers)
```

[[46325, 54326, 32666, 32453, 54325, 32542, 38573]]

How can I get rid of this extra bracket on the outside of the list? It is causing downstream issues.

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 4):

```
List_of_16419_Indivudual_Numbers[0:4499]
```

returns a list. You don't need to append it to another one. Try just this:

```
Original_List = [46325, 54326, 32666, 32453, 54325, 32542, 38573]

First_4500_Numbers = Original_List[0:4499]
```

Then output will look like

```
>>> print(First_4500_Numbers)
[46325, 54326, 32666, 32453, 54325, 32542, 38573]
```

Comment: You actually want `[0:4500]`; the last index is not included, so `[0:4500]` includes elements 0 through 4499, which is 4,500 elements.